# node.js mongoose find() method usage with key value in object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-schema

I'd like to find data from mongodb using find() function
Here is my schema

```
  const newcontractSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  creator: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: false,
    index: true,
  },
  status: {type: String, required: false, default: 'init'},
  a_status: {type: String, required: false, default: 'pending'},

  contractInfo: {
    startDate: {type: Date},
    endDate: {type: Date},
    expectedUsage: {type: Number, default: 2000},
    provider: {type: Object},
    rate: {type: Number},
    term: {type: Number},
    userid: {type: String}


}, {timestamps: true});
```

and what I tried is

```
Newcontract.find({contractInfo: {userid: {$eq: req.body.userid}}})
```

But I couldn't fetch data based on this userid in contractInfo object

How to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Minor note: it's a good practice to always use the `new` operator when constructring

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not querying correctly.

You need something like this:

```js
db.collection.find({
  "contractInfo.userid": "yourid"
})
```

Mongo playground example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fcR3hgTpQwf)

In `mongoose` will be very similar:

```js
Newcontract.findOne({
  "contractInfo.userid": req.body.id
})
```

Note that you can use `findOne()` to get only one object if you want.

Comment: Thanks, "contractInfo.userid": req.body.id
I tried with it but I can not see data
if I use Newcontract.find({status: "signed", a_status: req.body.a_status}) then this is finding data but if I use Newcontract.find({status: "signed", a_status: req.body.a_status, "contractInfo.userid": req.body.userid}) then no data is coming

Comment: So please, edit the question and add: Complete schema, a DB collection example and an expected output. Without knowing that is not easy find a solution.

Comment: @SS-Tobi I've tried the query with the schema and works for me. Can you check if  ```req.body.id``` is a value which exists into DB?

Comment: yes, I was wrong with userid, it's working fine now, thanks for your help